# How to reduce blender file size? (File over 1GB)

Tags: blend-files, file-format

[image]

Context: I am doing an interior render for a store concept. I am working on a 1:1 ratio.

This is my scene right now. Before I added the "Room 1 Installation" collection (which is in the furniture piece on the far left where the buddha statue is), my file size was around 140mb, somehow now the file size is 1.3GB and I can feel that its lagging. Could it be because of the number of meshes I have created? I didn't want to join them together because I was trying to have it non-destructive.

Edit: I also tried selecting all vertices and merging by distance, but it didn't affect the size that much (around 100mb).

*Also in another copy I deleted all the things I added since my file size was around 140mb, and surprisingly the file size is still 1.1GB now

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Edit #2: I found out that the strings that are supposed to attach the yin yang above the bonsai plant, took up to 600mb. Those were just a simple cylinder and I had subdivision solidifier applied to them.

Wireframe View:
[image]

I tried deleting these high poly objects in different copies of the project and I found out that the bonsai plant or even the rock dont affect the size that much. The statue definitely makes a difference (if I delete it, the file goes to about 140mb).
I'm fairly new to blender and still have a lot to learn. I'm going to look into the decimate modifier

Comment: You can check if the Buddha statue is extremely high-poly. Is it a scanned model? Then you could try to remesh it. Or does it come with a lot of high-res textures? Then you can replace them with resized versions of the same texture.

Comment: @michaelh I would say 90% of the meshes in the file are made out of cubes. I just learnt to link the similar ones together but It doesn't affect the file size that much (maybe a few mb). I tried delete the Buddha statue but it did only take about 100mb.

Comment: Many of the objects look very high-poly. The tree, the rock and the shelves with the grid-like walls for example. Quite likely you can use the "decimate"-modifier on these quite heavily to reduce poly-count without losing details noticeably!
If that does not work satisfactorily, please show us a wireframe view of your scene so we can identify the "troublemakers" more easily!

Comment: Have you tried the options in the File > Cleanup Menu? Maybe there is unused data lying around. (Meshs Datablocks will stay around until you restart Blender or Cleanup manually) If you use Remesh- or Decimate-Modifiers, remember you'll need to apply them to affect the file size. Bc otherwise the original mesh will still be there.

Comment: Also, the oval-ish things at the bottom of the image look unnecessarily highly detailed. When using the decimate-modifier, please be aware that for it to have an impact on the saved filesize, it needs to be applied. For performance however, the effect should be immediate.

Comment: @haarigertroll I tried using the modifier but it only affected the file size just a couple or mb. I didn't overdo it because they would have lost the shape. The only thing that still kept my file size up was the Buddha statue which I guess I should find another one because the statue itself was around 500mb.

Comment: Probably any statue you can download is going to be a photoscan, they require retopology before you can use them in any reasonable way.  If you found your answer, feel free to write an answer to this question and mark it solved when it is available to you.